# Repetition in code for routes in Flask (or Bottle)

Tags: python, flask

I have at least 10 routes like this:

```
@app.route("/foo/bar")
def foo_bar():
    return render_template('foo_bar.html')

@app.route("/foo/baz")
def foo_baz():
    return render_template('foo_baz.html')

...
```

Each name is repeated three times: the name of the route, the name of the Python function, the name of the template.

What is the standard way with Flask (or Bottle) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
@app.route("/foo/<arg>")
def foo_arg(arg):
    return render_template(f"foo_{arg}.html")
```

Comment: Thanks! I've done this multiple times in the past, I don't know what made me hesitate here hehe (maybe lack of sleep is the real reason!).